# C++ abuse of string concatenation

Tags: c++, string

So I've generated some code over the last few months, maybe more, where I've use the C++ string library to concatenate strings. Like so:

```
template< typename T >
string tostr( const T & val ); // implmented wherever

void somelibraryfunction( const char * );

// begin actual code

somelibraryfunction( ( "foo" + tostr( 5 ) ).c_str( ) );
```

This compiles and works fine. My concern is the string temporary that is created is destroyed after an address to it's `c_str` is taken, and I'm just relying on reading the recently freed but uncleared memory. Any thoughts?

Comment: why can't you just say "foo" + tostr(5)?

Comment: Because it won't compile, @Chubsdad. The library function doesn't accept a std::string, which is the result of the concatenation expression.

Comment: Why don't you write `somelibraryfunction(const std::string&)` ?

Comment: @billz Surprisingly, I don't write all the libraries! Shocking, I know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The temporary string is not destroyed until the entire statement has completed, which isn't until after the library function returns. As long as the function doesn't save a copy of that address somewhere for later use, your code is fine. (Storing a copy of the string *contents* is fine; it just shouldn't store the `char*` pointer value, which becomes invalid when the temporary string goes away.)